# Header floats and paragraphs itself randomly

Tags: html, css

Edit: With help of **vakho papidze**, I've managed to centre the header, however it still is separated (not inline) nor in its correct position. 
Here is a diagram of what I'm seeking in the final version: https://gyazo.com/3a71cc861daf2ec897cceed30d4bb576.

---

In the past, when i was using only 3 titles in the header, which relocate users to other pages, the headers were in line and in the correct positions. By adding an additional title, the whole header flips out and relocates itself at the top right corner of the page. Here you can check the code-pen of the page with misplaced header - https://codepen.io/valik140795/pen/qadXOo.

```
 <ul>
    <style>
.dropbtn {
background-color: #282828;
color: #AA9568;
padding: 0px;
font-size: 16px;
border: none;
cursor: pointer;
}

.dropbtn:hover, .dropbtn:focus {
background-color: #282828;
}


.dropdown {
position: relative;
z-index: 999;
display: inline-block;
}

.dropdown-content {
display: none;
position: fixed;
z-index: 999;
background-color: #282828;
min-width: 180px;
overflow: auto;
box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
}

.dropdown-content a {
color: #AA9568;
padding: 3px 5px;
text-decoration: none;
display: block;
}

.dropdown a:hover {background-color: #282828}

.show {display:block;}
</style>

<div class="dropdown">
<button onclick="myFunction()" class="dropbtn"><a href=#fab>ФАБРИКИ</a>        </button>
  <div id="myDropdown" class="dropdown-content">
<a href="#nobilis">Nobilis</a>
<a href="#colordeseda">Color de Seda</a>
<a href="#eugenio">Eugenio Colombo</a>
<a href="#libra">Libra</a>
  </div>
</div>

<script>
/* When the user clicks on the button,
toggle between hiding and showing the dropdown content */
function myFunction() {
document.getElementById("myDropdown").classList.toggle("show");
}

function filterFunction() {
var input, filter, ul, li, a, i;
input = document.getElementById("myInput");
filter = input.value.toUpperCase();
div = document.getElementById("myDropdown");
a = div.getElementsByTagName("a");
for (i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
    if (a[i].innerHTML.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > -1) {
        a[i].style.display = "";
    } else {
        a[i].style.display = "none";
    }
}
}
</script>

    <li>|</li>

  <ul>
    <style>
.dropbtn {
background-color: #282828;
color: #AA9568;
padding: 0px;
font-size: 16px;
border: none;
cursor: pointer;
}

.dropbtn:hover, .dropbtn:focus {
background-color: #282828;
}


.dropdown {
position: relative;
z-index: 999;
display: inline-block;
}

.dropdown-content {
display: none;
position: fixed;
z-index: 999;
background-color: #282828;
min-width: 180px;
overflow: auto;
box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
}

.dropdown-content a {
color: #AA9568;
padding: 3px 5px;
text-decoration: none;
display: block;
}

.dropdown a:hover {background-color: #282828}

.show {display:block;}
</style>



<div class="dropdown">
<button onclick="myFunction()" class="dropbtn"><a href=#fab>ДИЛЕРЫ</a>        </button>
  <div id="myDropdown" class="dropdown-content">
    <a href="#nobilis">Nobilis</a>
    <a href="#colordeseda">Color de Seda</a>
    <a href="#eugenio">Eugenio Colombo</a>
    <a href="#libra">Libra</a>
  </div>
</div>

<script>
/* When the user clicks on the button,
toggle between hiding and showing the dropdown content */
function myFunction() {
document.getElementById("myDropdown").classList.toggle("show");
}

function filterFunction() {
var input, filter, ul, li, a, i;
input = document.getElementById("myInput");
filter = input.value.toUpperCase();
div = document.getElementById("myDropdown");
a = div.getElementsByTagName("a");
for (i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
    if (a[i].innerHTML.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > -1) {
        a[i].style.display = "";
    } else {
        a[i].style.display = "none";
    }
}
}
</script>        

    <li>|</li>
    <li><a href="http://www.123contactform.com/form-2178643/My-        Form">Сотрудничество</a></li>
    <li>|</li>
    <li><a href="contact.html">Контакты</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change like this and will work:

```css
.block_header ul {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 61px;
    right: 0;
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
}
```

Comment: Gives me the following: https://gyazo.com/a19be600b35d574c4d0f8ae10d2a0b4b

Comment: How would i position it inline, if i already have
 
`code
   .block_header ul {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 61px;
    right: 0;
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
    display:inline;
    clear: none;
    white-space:normal;
    word-wrap:break-word;
`

Comment: I added just this and it works properly `width: 100%;
    text-align: center;`

Comment: Thank you, this actually centred everything, however it is still floating awkwardly and divides as a paragraph. Here is a graph of what I'm seeking as a final version: https://gyazo.com/3a71cc861daf2ec897cceed30d4bb576. Thanks for your help.